# Automated mounting for usb drives in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount

I have a five 4TB usb drives. I want to setup a mount point, `/mnt/backups` so that when I plug in any of those drives, they get automatically mounted to `/mnt/backups`.

The problem is that when the drive path changes all the time for the drives even though I put them in the same usb slot. I've seen /dev/sde1 through /dev/sdh1...

OS is Ubuntu.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? Is it the server or desktop version?

Comment: It's the server version.

Comment: And the version number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `/dev/disk`. There are some other ways to access the devices. `by-path` may suit your needs, dependent from the usb controllers in your drives. If this does not work you might just label (`e2label(8)`) your partitions and use `by-label`.

Comment: How do I mount a drive by its path? I'm assuming if I can mount a drive `by-path` then I can plug a different drive into the same usb slot and it will work.

Comment: in the `by-path` folder are symlinks to e.g. `/dev/sde1`. So you can just `mount /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:01:00.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1 /mnt/backups`. Some for `by-path`

Comment: And in laymens terms that path references the usb slot?

Comment: That depends on your drives usb controller. Just plug in your devices and check if the path changes. If you want to be sure use the `by-label` way.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you can use udev to define the disk locations as static as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your Ubuntu version, but 12.04 LTS will automatically mount USB devices and put them in /media/disklabel, where 'disklabel' is the actual name of the disk according to the partition metadata. This makes the path of the disk consistent across each mounting.